# Opening Cypress gives an error in not finding resource.pak

Tags: npm, cypress, npm-install

I'm trying to add End to End testing to my application through Cypress, however I've run into the issue that, after installing cypress through "npm install cypress" the command listed in their documentation "npx cypress open" will not work. It gives the following error.

`[35608:0112/105037.652:ERROR:resource_bundle.cc(991)] Failed to load C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\12.3.0\Cypress\resources.pak
Some features may not be available.
Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\12.3.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\socket\index.js`

What I've tried is a fresh reinstall of cypress, specifically adding socket.io and socket.io-client globally. I've also looked into the file path of resource.pak and have confirmed the folder is there.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Downgraded to 12.1.x to make it work again.

Answer (score 0):

Also had the problem.

run

`npm uninstall cypress`

`npm i cypress@12.10.0`